# AcessViolationException when reaching file properties in VS 2013 WP 8.1 Silverlight app

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to obtain properties from music files such as artist, album to display in my application, but when it reach the properties atribute the debugger throws an exception, can't post images so the message is:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in UberPlayer.ni.DLL

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

i was thinking that because it was on a foreach it was using a lot of memory and would breaks, but isolating the code like this:

```
IReadOnlyList<IStorageItemProperties> itemsListProperties = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                   var test = itemsListProperties.First().Properties;
```

still gets the exception message and the app crashes.

i'm new in WP programming but i think it shouldn't be a code error. any one nows?

also i run the debug on my phone cause my laptop can't emulate WP8.1

Comment: You need to await that call - GetFilesAsync() will not work synchronously, and calling GetResult() will break the execution in place.

Comment: but the getAwaiter already dont do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure out what happen,

looks like the type IStorageItemProprieties doesn't work to retrive properties from an item, funny that's him name, or maybe its depreceated.

it works with StorageFile type, also added some awaits, maybe i was going too fast? :p

```
IAsyncOperation<IReadOnlyList<StorageFile>> async = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
           var itemsList = await async;

           foreach (var item in itemsList)
           {
               var itemProp = item.Properties;
               var propMusic = await itemProp.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
               Music m1 = new Music(propMusic.Title, propMusic.Artist, propMusic.Album, propMusic.Genre.ToString(), propMusic.TrackNumber.ToString(), propMusic.Duration, item.Path);
               _listMusic.Add(m1);
           }
           return _listMusic;
```

thanks to all who contributed to discussion.